# Micronaut as OAuth2 Client

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, microservices, micronaut

**Given:**

I have a Micronaut application that provides diverent endpoints which are secured using OAuth2 and Keycloak. A user needs to login and gets a token.
The application needs to access other microservices. Those other endpoints are also secured with OAuth2 tokens. The tokens are machine2machine tokens, so no user login is required.

**Problem:**

The HttpClients for accessing other microservices need a OAuth2 machine2machine token. The micronaut application should request this token at a given token endpoint using a client id and a client secret. I did not found any documentation about this. Has someone already solved this problem or a good documentation about it?

Comment: Are you asking for how to do the client credentials grant? If so its not supported out of the box. See https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-security/issues/12. You could of course implement it yourself

Comment: Yes, that is exactly, what I am trying too.
Too bad, that it is no supported out of the box. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look for the feature in the release version of 1.2 (not released yet)

Comment: @JamesKleeh do you know when it will be released?